# Layout broken and way off: image positioning differs between FireFox and Chrome/Edge

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser, flexbox

In an overview of many tiny images **of variying sizes** (first image in one, second in two and all the rest in three images per row layout) all works beautifully ordered in FireFox: neat layout with the second image in the middle on a three row span.

But then I tested it in Chrome and MS Edge only to discover that the layout was all over the place (see images). The essential code is [JSFIDDLE Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/v9s5ymbr/).

```
logo3 :nth-child(2) img{margin: 0 auto}
logo3 :last-child   img{float:  right}
```

1. Whats the reason behind this rendering engine difference between FireFox, and Chrome/Edge?
2. How to fix this in CSS-only, so Edge/Chrome works the same way as FireFox does? Thanks!

---

Left: **FireFox** v54. Right: **Chrome** v59. All on Windows 10 machine. Look at the middle column!
[image]  [image]

---

Left: **Chrome** v59. Right: Microsoft **Edge** v38. These two look identical.
[image]  [image]

Comment: logo1, logo2 and logo3 are not HTML elements. Change them into <div class="logo1"> etc and it will be ok.

Comment: @Gerard Thanks you sound very certain! I changed all html elements to divs with ids, and all css accordingly: The exact same results as before, as with the custom html elements remain, even with <div id="div3"> and #div3 etc. With normal divs it is rendered in the exact same way in all three browsers as the images I already have provided here. So you are wrong: that is not it! PS all please place your answers as answers not as comments sothat others can upvote/comment your provided solutions. Thanks

Comment: In addition to giving each img *width: 100%*, give them *height: auto*. See if that works.

Comment: Also, we could help you more effectively if you include a complete demo that reproduces the problem, with the code posted in the question itself.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using custom elements.

Comment: Sam, that's not correct. I saw the fiddle. There are no images inside, just broken links, so the problem is not reproduced. Plus, it's always better to include the code in the question itself. If the jsfiddle link stops working one day, for whatever reason, your question becomes useless as a source of reference.

Comment: You are right, forgive me I THOUGHT this was a simple quesion and someone knowledgable would immediately see and say this one line will solve it but apparently its more complex! I thought and think any image links will do! Apparently its more difficult than I thought. Perhaps Stackoverflow is not the correct place to ask my question (I have a -1 downvote after all this effort with images and clear question pfff). Thank you for your time all but this is not motivating me nor you so lets just forget it.

Comment: Your first sentence in your last comment may be true, but it's not really relevant. For the sake of quality, usefulness and adherence to SO guidelines you should post your code in the question. Then, just post the full image URLs so we can see the varying heights and actual problem.

Comment: Funny the more time I spend to make the essence of the problem clearer and more generic in a concise way, the more downvotes I get.

Comment: @Michael_B, I dont agree: I dont think that finishing my generic clear question off with some real links to png images would make it any better: the links will eventually break making my question not future proof! On the other hand the jsfiddle will always work: just replace my sample own links with your own and you have the problem recreated! Any person can add 3 png links of their own in the three row elements and have the problem recreated. But apparently nobody bothered! I am sorry that replacing three hyperlinks to some random png images to try was such a pain. Never mind mate!

Comment: Good news, a single (short!) line of css code with 1 magic css property solved this puzzle, thanks to @Gerard! Thank You So Much!! Awesome! Could have never solved this by myself!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I have tested this with Chrome 59.0.3071.115, Firefox 54.0.1 and Edge 40.15063.0.0. They looked identical.

EDIT: `logo1 a, logo2 a, logo3 a { flex: 1; }` added.

```css
body {
  width: 300px
}

logo1,
logo2,
logo3 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
}

logo1 a,
logo2 a,
logo3 a {
  flex: 1;
}

logo1 img,
logo2 img,
logo3 img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  outline: 1px solid #000;
}

logo1 img {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0
}

logo2 img {
  width: 95%;
  margin: 10px 0
}

logo2 :last-child img {
  float: right
}

logo3 img {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 10px 0
}

logo3 :nth-child(2) img {
  margin: 0 auto
}

logo3 :last-child img {
  float: right
}
```

```html
<logo1>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://hubspotleiden.nl/media/uploads/partners/gemeente-leiden.png" /></a>
</logo1>

<logo2>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://www.aanmelder.nl/resources/img/references/Universiteit%20Leiden.png" /></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://hartlongcentrum.nl/themes/hartlongcentrum/images/lumc_logo.png" /></a>
</logo2>

<logo3>
  <a href="#"><img src="http://www.begrotingzuidholland.nl/assets/img/logo.png" /></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://www.fryslan.frl/templates/images/flex-v9/logo.png" /></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://www.fryslan.frl/plaat.php?fileid=13276&f=d84cea4401ac79c2f1fee09119068905413ea0bf339c69a0477f2f531c96c7e6fdbcff8b99f4eb9b4d3b491af4ea91fe2fa0cc18fbcf450f49de23164166e7f5" /></a>
</logo3>

<logo3>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/51/IBM_logo.svg/2000px-IBM_logo.svg.png" /></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="http://www.magnus.nl/wp-content/uploads/2012/10/Sandd.png" /></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://static.thuisbezorgd.nl/images/restaurants/nl/3OQ3P/logo_465x320.png" /></a>
</logo3>

<logo3>
  <a href="#"><img src="http://www.kringloopwarenhuis.nl/images/Piezo_logo.png" /></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://static.thuisbezorgd.nl/images/restaurants/nl/30R5151/logo_465x320.png" /></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f3/LIFF_zonder_datum.png" /></a>
</logo3>

<logo3>
  <a href="#"><img src="http://www.clcvecta.nl/content/user/1/images/voorstellen-homepage/Logo%20RAI%20Amsterdam.png" /></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/bf/LG_logo_%282015%29.svg/800px-LG_logo_%282015%29.svg.png" /></a>
  <a href="#"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/13/Christen_Democratisch_App%C3%A8l_%28nl%29_Logo.svg/1024px-Christen_Democratisch_App%C3%A8l_%28nl%29_Logo.svg.png" /></a>
</logo3>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Gerard  here I can see immediately that your answer will not replacate my situation for as you can see on my postes printscreens: all images are of variying sizes! Sure if all imges were 50x50 in a three colum layout (as in your code) in all browsers they would fit neatly! That is not the problem that is presented here. The problem is that when all images are of varieing size, in my CSS code FireFox does treat them "equally" providing a neat structured layout no matter what the image width and height are, while the other browsers do not.

Comment: If you can provide the full location of your images, I'd be quite happy to use them instead of the 50x50

Comment: Thanks, well if it helps, I have updated my JSFiddle with some working links to mimick the (my personal situation) as realistically as possible. I actually tried to avoid this first to keep my question "more generic" but since you and Michel_B asked, I provided the more elaborate version. I also updated the images in my question that is costing me more downvotes than solutions.

Comment: I can see a difference in the size of the images, but not as much as in your examples. I need to look into it in more detail to figure out what the reason could be.

Comment: LOL thats the first sensible, intelligent, logical and true statement I have seen on this website today! +1  (PS jsfiddle updated for clearer difference!) Thanks mate

Comment: PS also add `body{width: 300px}` to your css or use the updated JSfiddle in quetsion. Open the jsfiddle in three browsers and you will see that FireFox is the only one showcasing all columns neatly, *regardless of the image sizes* in the three columns. This is what I want to achieve in the other two browsers as well.

Comment: I think logo1 a, logo2 a, logo3 a { flex: 1;  } does the trick.

Comment: Absolutely awesome mate! That single line of code was what solved my puzzle! A hug and a big thank you. Answer accepted! All browsers have exact same good layout now! Brilliant!